# Protocol Not Calling

Tags: ios, swift2

I have created a protocol `MainMenuDelegate`. But it is not calling.

In my MainMenu

```
import UIKit
    @objc
    protocol MainMenuDelegate {
        optional func toggleLeftPanel()
       }
    class MainMenu: UIViewController {
        var delegate: DashBoard!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @IBAction func selectAction(sender:UIButton) {
                delegate?.toggleLeftPanel()
        }

    }
```

In DashBoard

```
import UIKit
@objc

    protocol DashBoardDelegate {

    }
    class DashBoard: UIViewController {
        var delegate: MainMenu?
        var a : MainMenu!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.a = MainMenu()
        self.a.delegate = self
        }
    }
    extension DashBoard : MainMenuDelegate
    {
        func toggleLeftPanel()
        {
            print("afgygfy")
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your viewDidLoad you are creating a new instance of MainMenu, not using the existing one

Comment: @MidhunMP how we overcome this...

Comment: You need to specify what is MainMenu and What is Dashboard ? How both are related, so that we can help you

Comment: MainMenu is my another controller and dashBoard is anotherController. I want to click button on MainMenu Controller call method of dashBoard.it is demo we want to make Drawer.

Comment: did you import the related delegate of "mainMenu"at header of "dashboard "?

Comment: @priyankagautam: You need to set the delegate from where you are creating those view controller's for the first time. If you are looking for slide-out menu, please check this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in the way your are connecting and using your view controllers. I am sure you are not using the right object when calling delegate method.

I created a sample in playground and could manage to call the delegate method. The key lines here are last 4 lines which shows the usage of object. I am not creating a new `MainMenu` object and using the one which was created in the `Dashboard`. For storyboard sake I replaced view controller methods with my own methods.

```
@objc

protocol DashBoardDelegate {

}
class DashBoard: UIViewController {
    var delegate: MainMenu?
    var a : MainMenu!

    func dash() {
        self.a = MainMenu()
        self.a.delegate = self
    }
}

extension DashBoard : MainMenuDelegate
{
    func toggleLeftPanel()
    {
        print("afgygfy")
    }
}

@objc
protocol MainMenuDelegate {
    optional func toggleLeftPanel()
}
class MainMenu: UIViewController {
    var delegate: DashBoard!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func takeAction() {
        print(delegate)
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel()
    }

}


var dash = DashBoard()
dash.dash()

var main = dash.a
main.takeAction()
```

Comment: Hasn't this got more to do with how one view controller presents another, and how during that presentation the presenting view controller can set properties on the presented view controller?

Comment: There is a very thin line here but to some extent yes. It all depends how you are connecting 2 view controllers via a contract called protocol. Parties on both the should be same while making the contract and while executing it!

Comment: I didn't understand your last sentence.

Comment: I meant you got to work with right objects when it comes to protocols. I think OP created initalized one `MainMenu` object and when trying to call delegate, calling on different `MainMenu` object.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the issue.  However I would assume the OP doesn't actually know how the first view controller creates and presents the second view controller.  Your answer won't help him as he simply does not understand this relationship.

Comment: Well, I would want to hear from OP on that. Moreover, I have pointed out in my example how I used the objects. I hope she understand it. Would be happy to guide further if need be.

Comment: @Abhinav thanks for great help where we put four line

Comment: Could you please accept this answer if it resolved your problem. @priyankagautam